# Conditionally Display text on a button when input changes

Tags: jquery, button, text, toggle

I have got a file input field on a form. I am changing the text of the button dynamically depending on whether the input field has a file uploaded or not. It works fine except that I have to refresh the page so that the text changes. I want the text to toggle instantly depending on the status of the input..

**Input field**

```
 <input type="file" name="frontSide" id="frontSide" class="form-input" value="" style="margin-top: -30px;" data-parsley-doc = '' accept=".doc, .docx, .pdf" required>
```

**Button that am changing the text dynamically**

```
    <button type="submit" id="btnFront" value="" style="cursor: pointer;" class="jenga" disabled></button>
```

**Conditionally toggle button text**

```
if ($('#frontSide').get(0).files.length === 1) {
         $("#btnFront").html('Thanks, Upload Back Side >>');
     }
     else{
        $("#btnFront").html('Upload Front Side');
     }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Listen to your input's [`change`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/change) event:

```
$('#frontSide').on('change', /* ... */);
```

**Demo**:

```js
$(function() {
  function updateUploadBtnText() {
    if ($('#frontSide').get(0).files.length === 1) {
      $("#btnFront").html('Thanks, Upload Back Side >>');
    } else {
      $("#btnFront").html('Upload Front Side');
    }
  }
  
  $('#frontSide').on('change', updateUploadBtnText);

  updateUploadBtnText();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" name="frontSide" id="frontSide" class="form-input" value="" style="margin-top: -30px;" data-parsley-doc='' accept=".doc, .docx, .pdf" required>

<button type="submit" id="btnFront" value="" style="cursor: pointer;" class="jenga" disabled></button>
```